# Undefined SP.ClientContext

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I always get undefined on my `SP.ClientContext.get_current()`

I have tried with this code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',runthiscode);

function runthiscode(){

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js','SP.UserProfiles',initialize);

}
```

And this code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "SP.UserProfiles.js");
```

I use this code for all scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.jQuery == undefined) 
 document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="../style library/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"    type="text/javascript"%3E%3C/script%3E') );
 document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/_layouts/15/SP.js" type="text/javascript"%3E%3C/script%3E') );
 document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js" type="text/javascript"%3E%3C/script%3E') );
</script>
```

The script is working if the newform.aspx is in edit page, then it autofill my columns from mysite information.

Update!

I got SP.js working, but not for userprofiles.js this is the code that is working for now:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);

ctx.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
});

function example () {
}
window.onload = example;
```

So what can the problem be with the userprofiles ?

Update,

With this code above i cant push the button save

Answer (score 3):

You can load your JS files directly, you don't need to do document.write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.userprofiles.js"></script>
```

For your, js code, try loading those within dom ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js', 'SP.UserProfiles', initialize);
    });
});
```

Comment: it still not working, it only works when i am in edit mode for newform.aspx. Its just this newform.aspx that this script is not working..

Comment: If you can edit NewForm.aspx using designer, add those script reference within ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead". See if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's because all the SharePoint JavaScript-Files are not ready when you try to access your context. Instead of document.ready or similar, try this:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName"); //waits for all SP-Scripts

function myCustomFunctionName() {
     // My custom functionality
}
```

Comment: I tried that also

Comment: Ok thank you all for the help. i recogniced a fault collumn in my newform that gave me a unload of the page. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Khristopher's example for workflows, I was able to get this working for user profiles in display and edit modes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.UserProfiles', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('SP.UserProfiles.js'));
        SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.UserProfiles'], function () {
            var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
        userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
        clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
        });
    }, "sp.js");
}, "sp.runtime.js");

function onSuccess() {      
  alert(userProfileProperties.get_displayName());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
  alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when I am working with WorkflowServices. I imagine that it would be very similar for your UserProfiles example:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('SP.WorkflowServices.js'));
        SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager'], function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
            var instanceService = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
        });
    }, "sp.js");
}, "sp.runtime.js");
```