# Sharepoint 2013 and ajax problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ajax, branding

I used that Ajax branding technique to load list items or any document library item into my design in Sharepoint 2010 now im working on 2013 and with the same technique i got failure

```
$.ajax({
url: '~/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx',
data:{id:"#divId"},
dataType: "html"
success: function(data){
console.log($(data).find('table[summary="Awr Latest"]'));
}

});
```

in 2010 i got response with the table of content that i need
now im getting a response with the masterpage and the content div but no table in it

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 uses a lot of client side rendering. This means while you load the content of your AllItems.aspx page, the list rows aren't contained in the html response.
They would rendered dynamic via JavaScript.

But anyway, your ajax techique is very bad to get list items. ;)

### Use something like this (it's called Java Script Object Model / JSOM):

```
function getListItems(onSuccess) {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
    var collListItem;

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var viewXML = '<View><Query><OrderBy></OrderBy><Where></Where></Query><RowLimit>5000</RowLimit></View>';
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(viewXML);
    
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            // We have the elements
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            // It's easy to iterate and get the column values of an item
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var cItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                console.log('Id: ' + cItem.get_id() + ', Title: ' + cItem.get_item('Title'));                           
            }

            // Run callback function if needed
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(collListItem);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Error getting list items: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
 }

 // Run the function if SharePoint DOM and Object Model is ready
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('getListItems');
```

Comment: Thank you im Learning from you
i'll try your code now :)

Comment: now i got error 
    SP.ClientContext.get_current()
undifined  !

Comment: i replaced get_current() with site url
the same error

Comment: Did you take this function and included the line with _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push on your page? I think you are trying to call SP.ClientContext **before** SharePoint Object Model is ready. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105667/undefined-sp-clientcontext

Comment: Yeah i used that line but the same error
here is it from the console
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined

Comment: Can you post your code on a pastebin? Maybe I see the error. Otherwise I think you should read some tutorials about JSOM.

Comment: Its Exactly the code you just sent
i think the problem would be in my masterpage head
http://pastebin.com/AgCWQZMN

Comment: take a look at it

Comment: this file 
    <script src="/Style Library/awr/js/DataAjax.js"></script>

in the scripts which has the list retrieving code

Comment: You need to include SP.JS file as well in the master page`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="SP.js"  />`

Comment: When i included SP.js 

Cannot read property 'majorVersion' of undefined

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. You're welcome. :) PS: You can mark this answer as correct/accepted with the hooklet button.

Answer (score 0):

Now it Works after i added

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
```

before any Scripts

Comment: Seeing the help provide by Fensterbank, I would have expected that you marked his response as answer instead of adding yours.

Comment: aHA YES REALLY IM KINDA NEW USER HERE 
STILL UNDERSTANDING THERES NO WAY TO DO IT NOW ?

Comment: thank u also u are noticed the sp.js that was the problem really thanks Nadeem